# How to remove double quotes from json array data object

Tags: php, web-services

I want to remove double quotes from json data object.

i have tried many ways but still my numeric is showing in double
quotes.

here is my code ..

```
<?php 
 $m_nu= str_replace('"', ' ', $mobile_number);
 $skt1['mobile_number'] =  str_replace('"', " ", json_encode($mobile_number, JSON_HEX_APOS));
?>
```

**it's given output like**

```
<?php 
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Profile updated successfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "user_id": 11,
      "Email": "make_jackson@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "make",
      "last_name": "Jackson",
      "mobile_number": "9856898998",
      "user_image": ""
    }
  ]
}

?>
```

**and i want like**

```
<?php 
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Profile updated successfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "user_id": 11,
      "Email": "make_jackson@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "make",
      "last_name": "Jackson",
      "mobile_number": 9856898998,
      "user_image": ""
    }
  ]
}
?>
```

when i tried string to number by using

```
<?php (int)$mobile_number;?>
```

it's working good but problem is original value are changed and output
given like below.

```
<?php 
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Profile updated successfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "user_id": 11,
      "Email": "make_jackson@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "make",
      "last_name": "Jackson",
      "mobile_number": 2147483647,
      "user_image": ""
    }
  ]
}
?>
```

My mobile number value are changed original value is **9856898998**
and it's return **2147483647**.

Comment: A 32-bit integer value will never be larger than 2147483647. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)#In_computing

Comment: php will itself take care of number and string after `json _decode`

Comment: you cannot convert it to int because it exceeds the limit of int

Comment: That said, a phone number should actually be a string. What happens if you parse a string containing only numerics, starting with a `0`, to an integer? The preceding `0` will disappear.

Comment: i have tried without convert it but still value is appearing in double quotes.

Comment: i passed phone number as a string.

Comment: @sameersheikh: And it should stay a string. If you wish to remove the quotes from the result, it will no longer be a string.

Comment: @AuditeMarlow : i understood  what you said  , i keep phone number as a sting but problem is android developer required it in number format not in double quotes.

Comment: Why are you converting to int and not accept as string ?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra : ok i am not convert it to int but i tried with str_replace function still it's appearing in double quotes.

Comment: @sameersheikh : and whats the problem because of double quotes ? just decode that json using json_decode() which gives a data without quotes

Comment: @RakeshSojitra: i sent data with json_decode().

Answer (score 0):

Type (float) instead of (int), The int's max value is 2147483647 and you can't use int higher then that number... so you can Just use float...

Comment: This is bad practice for storing phone numbers. What happens if your phone number starts with `0`?

Comment: It's anyway bad practice to change string to Int, or float in json)) It is a small solution for this problem, not more.

Comment: Anyway you must use Or float numbers that can't start from 0, or String. It's your own choice